# COUNTIFS with >=, wrong data type

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, microsoft-excel-2016

I can't get my excel formula working. `ZÄHLENWENNS` is `COUNTIFS`

```
=ZÄHLENWENNS(A:A;A2;C2;C2>=18)
```

I always get:

> A Value used in this formula is of the wrong data type

Here is an excerpt of the sheet

```
UserId  User-Count  Duration
144     #WERT!      18
78599   #WERT!      1
15033   #WERT!      14
77529   #WERT!      20
144     #WERT!      19
```

I want to the count how often a user has a duration equal or greater than 18(max is 20).

So the desired result would be:

```
UserId  User-Count  Duration
144     2           18
78599   0           1
15033   0           14
77529   1           20
144     2           19
144     2           17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to change your second criteria area to `C:C`. Then you have to change your second criteria to `">=18"` so your function reads

```
=ZÄHLENWENNS(A:A;A2;C:C;">=18")
```

Then it will work.